# Empty Package (model) in generated client jar

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an app engine app that I want to expose its data to android app. I can test the endpoint's method just fine using curl/the explorer. However when I generated the android client using:

```
endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . -f rest api.MyApi
```

and included the generated subdomain-myapp-v1-20130522125850-java-1.15.0-rc-sources.jar in the /libs folder of my android app, eclipse shows the empty package icon of com.google.api.services.mypp.model where it should contain the model class. I also tried to include the generated jar's dependencies into my android libs folder too with no result.

Thinking that my app engine implementation might be flawed, I [downloaded](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python) the app engine app tictactoe and generated the client code and include it in my android app. But, still empty package. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to write the [model classes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android/tree/master/src/com/google/api/services/tictactoe/model) and it will not be auto generated. Maybe auto generation works when you are building a java app engine backend through Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Is that really the case? Because the python documentation for the generated client libraries said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently one have to extract the generated bla-bla-sources.jar inside the zip file and copied them into the Android project to make it work. Maybe I'm missing a simpler way to do it (I thought I can just include that sources.jar file like its dependencies into the Android project) but for now this is my only solution that works. I hope it helps anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: I went the same route. I extracted the *.java files from the jar file.
`jar -xvf blah-blah-sources.jar`
Then I copied the files to my Android project.